# Wordpress - put facebook / twitter login buttons in header

Tags: facebook, wordpress, twitter, authentication

I am working on [this website](http://kristinaartgallery.ru) and I want to add facebook and twitter login buttons to header, just like it's done [on this website](http://a-a-ah.ru). How do I do that?

As you can see, I am a noob, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of social login pulgins are available for this kind of module. you can try with this https://wordpress.org/plugins/loginradius-for-wordpress/screenshots/ or use any other social login plugin which ever suits your theme.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out myself already, via fb / twi developer tools. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can do with the fb / twi developer tools , but configuration with plugins lot easier and handy, using short code or widget you can put any where .